# Failed to open the file in the Scene Builder / IntelJ

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have been trying to open the fxml file in my JavaFX project but I keep getting this error

[image]

In my first try, I used the [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) Scene Builder then I tried the [Gluon][4] Scene Builder and in both cases I got the same error. How to fix this problem?

Comment: IntelliJ has a built-in Scene Builder (kit), it doesn't depend on your external Scene Builder standalone application. There is a known [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209562) if you run with Java 11, but it should be solved with IntelliJ 2019.3 (ea).

Comment: Also, I think it is preferred to post actual test of errors not screenshots. More people will be willing to help if they don't have to transcribe tiny text from a screenshot first.